# How do I write a while loop inside an if statement if I want to ask user to add elements to the list

Tags: python

I want the program to ask user to add something to the list, then ask him if its all. If no, the while loop keeps asking to add until he's done and then the program prints the list with all the added elements.

Not sure how to do this, I'm a beginner, program keeps ignoring my while loop.

```
shopping_cart = []



statement = input("Do you want to add an item to the cart?: ")
added_items = ""

if statement == "yes":
    while len(added_items) == " ":
        added_items = shopping_cart.append(input("What item to add?: "))
    print(shopping_cart)
elif statement == "no":
    print(shopping_cart)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Please provide the code sample you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i ask user for input continuously until they say "Stop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475405/how-do-i-ask-user-for-input-continuously-until-they-say-stop)

Comment: The built-in function *len()* will return an *int* but you're trying to compare that with a *str*

Comment: Does `len(added_items) == " "` really make sense to you? why would a number be equal to a string?

Comment: Why would a value ```len(added_items)``` be equal to a string ```" "```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting user input and the if statement should be inside the the while loop so that the system keeps looping till user type no

```
shopping_cart = []

while True:
    statement = input("Do you want to add an item to the cart? (yes/no): ")
    if statement.lower() == "yes":
        item = input("What item to add?: ")
        shopping_cart.append(item)
    elif statement.lower() == "no":
        break

print("Items in your shopping cart:", shopping_cart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *while* loop can be based on the input value. Any input other than "yes" will break the loop.

Like this:

```
shopping_cart = []

while input("Do you want to add an item to the cart?: ") == "yes":
    item = input("What item to add?: ")
    shopping_cart.append(item)

print(shopping_cart)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You have declared `added_item` as a blank string. So if you start the while statement as `while len(added_item)== " "`, It will check
   the number of characters(length) in the variable `added_item`.
2. The `while loop` should contain increment or decrement condition for the loop to continue. (like `i += 1`). Also as per the above requirement, the order of the algorithm should be changed.
3. As the while loops condition tends to create an endless loop, a `break` statement is required.

   ```
   shopping_cart = []
   i = 0
   while i >= 0:
       statement = input("Do you want to add an item to the cart?:\n")
       if statement == "yes":
           shopping_cart.append(input("What item to add?:\n"))
       else:
           print(f'Your cart : \n{shopping_cart}')
           break

       i += 1

   '''input: 
   yes
   umbrella
   yes
   key chain
   yes
   rubiks cube
   no

   output:
   Do you want to add an item to the cart?:
   What item to add?:
   Do you want to add an item to the cart?:
   What item to add?:
   Do you want to add an item to the cart?:
   What item to add?:
   Do you want to add an item to the cart?:
   Your cart : 
   ['umbrella', 'key chain', 'rubiks cube']
   '''
   ```

Comment: You never use *i* so you might as well use *while True*

Comment: I understand. But for single product, why does the OP need to declare a list?(shopping_cart). So, I thought OP wants to do for multiple products